What is the name of this 90's-2000's sci fi movie?
I remember little about the movie, but the plot was so:
In a modern world, wizard or mages or sorcerers exist, and there are magic items.
One very powerful item is a staff, which one family man has. He hides the staff and leaves a clue for his son. The father is killed. When the son comes of age, he has to find or finds the staff and the "evil wizards" hunt him down.
I remember a major element was traveling through a desert dimension for traversing vast distances in the real world.
Another scene was a man teleporting or going into the aforementioned dimension by unwrapping himself like you would a mummy :)
There was another scene where the son and his love interest are in an elevator and the floor starts to fall apart, but its only illusion, so they try to ignore the illusion else they actually fall through the floor.

Perhaps this would be better placed on Sci-Fi & Fantasy.

@AndrewThompson, this is on topic here, so there's no reason to move it: S&F certainly would extend such a consideration our way...

@JohnSmithOptional  Did I say it was off-topic?

@AndrewThompson Did I say that you said it was off-topic? ;-)

I am absolutely not sure, but some of your images, modern world with sorcerers, a staff, different dimensions, evokes memories to the Rutger Hauer movie Crossworlds that I saw a very long time ago and only have rather vague memories of.

A young man discovers that his father was from another dimension and that he is the key to the operation of a crystal that can be the deciding factor in a war crossing the dimensions.

Here's the original trailer:


 
