Man carries amber coloured stone and straps it to a wood staff
All I remember is a scene in a desert where a man holds the staff and the magic crystal or stone is strapped to the staff with a thin leather strap.
Live action and they spoke english (not sure if American or UK). I have a feeling the actor was Rutger Hauer but probly mixing him up with someone else. I saw it early 90s and it may have contained time travel so can't pin point when it was set.
Another scene that seems like its from the same movie is one where the characters have to walk between two specific palm trees in th hotel carpark before they can walk through the room door. If they do it leads them to a warehouse, if they don't it just takes them into a hotel room like any other.

You don't remember anything else? The possible language, country, year, genre, plot, specific scenes, where you saw it, what the actor looked like and whether it was animated or not? Help us out here. :)

This question is lacking sufficient content to be considered on quality enough to remain open.  Please edit your question to include as much information as you can remember, or else this question will most likely be closed.

Raiders of the Lost Ark? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_SGlGHF_XQ

Ladyhawke (1985)?

Not Ladyhawke, Dlind Fury or Omega Doom as I own these on DVD. I may have the actor mixed up simply because I watched his movies at the same age and I looked through his IMDB with no result. Thanks though @dav1dsm1th

Thank you for the extra details. Much clearer and a possible match posted.

Rutger Hauer, a magic staff? Whoa, Crossworlds really seems to be very famous on this site: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21690/49, http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28000/49. ;-)

Ah I searched this site three times to see if anyone asked something similar. Crossworlds is definately it. Thank you @Walt and all involved

I think you're after Crossworlds from 1996:

College student Joe is drawn into a battle to save the world from arch-enemy Ferris. Joe's heirloom pendant just happens to be the key to a sceptre that opens doors to the Crossworlds, another dimension. When Laura (Andrea Roth) shows up to check on the key and Ferris' goons begin their assaults, they run to semi-retired adventurer A.T. (Rutger Hauer) for help and guidance.

You can see the sceptre right there in the poster. And here's a bit on IMDb about the weird mechanics of this film:

You have a staff and a crystal. You put the two things together, and you have a key. You take the key and wack something real good with it and it opens a dimensional portal. You jump through the dimensional portal and voilà, new reality (or inter-reality travel, apparently). The reason Rutger Hauer's workshop wasn't there the first time the kid went back was because he hadn't passed behind the palm tree first -- that much, to me anyhow, was crystal clear.

There were already 2 similar questions about this film (here and here). Here's the trailer:



